# How do I set a custom date format in an auto-updating field in Powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm using Office 365, and trying to insert an auto-updating date field in the format YYYY-MM-DD. However, the Date And Time dialogue box only allows a set list of date formats, none of which match the ISO 8601 standard.

Is there any way of adding a custom number format to get the date in a logical order?

[image: Powerpoint standard date formats]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options in the list PPT hands you, the first if memory serves, will be whatever you've set in Windows as your date format.  If you customize that (Control Panel | Region & Language | Formats | Additional Settings | Date ) it'll be available in PPT.

On your own computer.

Other than a very complicated add-in solution, there's no way to customize it for other users.

Comment: That'll solve it, at least for this project. Strange that they don't allow custom formats in Powerpoint itself. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried it - sadly, the system format doesn't show up in the list. Thanks for trying, anyway.

Comment: @AndrewPerry It works here.  For example, I was able to set the short date to be 07,,22,,2019 (way more commas than any growing boy ought to eat).  You must be sure to click APPLY in the dialog box though.

Comment: Yup. I've got the OS set to the Swedish standard - YYYY-MM-DD - and have had for years, but it still doesn't show up in Powerpoint. It's quite irksome.

Comment: Two thoughts:  1) might you be using the web-based version of PPT? If so, I don't think that changing your local time/date settings would affect it.  And 2) , grasping at the nearest straws, do you think there's a disconnect between Swedish OS settings and the fact that the language shows up as English in the dialog above?

Comment: Using the standard version of Office 365. It could be a disconnect between Swedish OS and English Office, but going from memory it's an English version of Windows too. I think it might just be one of those weird little oversights MS are so keen on leaving in eight generations after they should have been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use your own custom date formatting string, but you can use the predefined format "YYYY-MM-DD" like this:

1. Go to PowerPoint Options->Language and add "English (Canada)" or "Swedish (Sweden)" as an additional document editing language.
2. In your date/time field, select that language, and a "YYYY-MM-DD" date format will be available; for "Swedish (Sweden)" optionally with 24 hour time ("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm").
3. The selected language choice will persist in this date/time field - also for other users who receive this presentation and did not follow step 1  - until they change the field to another language.